# "Unknown Provider" in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load a few services and controllers into an AngularJS app but I am facing an "Unknown Provider" message that I don't understand.

```
Unknown provider: $scope, accountManagementServiceProvider <- $scope,
accountManagementService <- RegistrationSigninControllerS/<@https:
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/an… id
```

My app.js is like this

```
var dataApp = angular.module('niwadataApp', ['ngRoute','niwaDataControllers']);
```

along with some config stuff and routes etc etc. Then in a separate file I define some settings and attempt to load the services/controller

```
dataApp.value('isEmbedded', false); //And the other 'auth' settings

dataApp.service('authenticationService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$location', 'authTimeout', 'authTimeoutUrl', 'authUrl',AuthenticationServiceImpl]);
dataApp.factory('authenticatingProxyService', ['authenticationService', 'isEmbedded', '$http', '$q', '$window', '$rootScope', AuthenticatingProxyServiceImpl]);
dataApp.service('accountManagementService', ['$q', 'authenticatingProxyService', AccountManagementServiceImpl]);
dataApp.controller('RegistrationSigninController', ['$scope, accountManagementService', RegistrationControllerImpl]);
```

The classes are all defined in their own files that are loaded before app.js, e.g.

```
var AccountManagementServiceImpl = function($q, auth) {
```

According to the error message it is looking for `accountManagementServiceProvider` but I've got a class called `accountManagementServiceImpl` and that is what I've specified in the `dataApp.service(` call. Have I missed something in the documentation that defines class names must end with 'Provider'? Which provider does it not know about? As far as I can see each controller, service and factory defines its requirements and should be able to be created.

Comment: No, angular behind the seens when you create a factory or service will create you the provider. This is just a red herring in terms of providers, what it is saying is that it can find the service, so it hasn't been loaded. If you can show files, file names, the order it is being loaded in, check chrome/firefox sources to make sure you can see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some quotes.

Change this:

```
dataApp.controller('RegistrationSigninController', ['$scope, accountManagementService', RegistrationControllerImpl]);
```

to this:

```
dataApp.controller('RegistrationSigninController', ['$scope', 'accountManagementService', RegistrationControllerImpl]);
```

Comment: D'oh! Thank you sooooo much, I've been staring at that for most of a day now!